# I get the error "Process exiting with code: -4058 signal: false." every time I run go code using the option to run with out debugging

Tags: go

I get the above error when running Go code from Visual Studio Code 1.51.1 When I run any To code outside of debug I get the error. If I run with debug everything works as expected. I have compiled the code to make and .exe and it runs with no errors. This just started on Friday 12/4/2020. I don't recall doing an update to Visual Studio Code or to my Go environment but something must have changed.

My original question was closed with the reason give that I did not give enough information about the the problem. I don't know what more information I can add. I have described the exact problem. Visual Studio Code will not execute the GO code unless it is running it as a debug session.It throws the above error and I can't find out what the error is or why Visual Studio Code started doing this all of a sudden. Another has asked this same question but it was closed for the same reason.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You had better do not post this kind of questions here at stackoverflow. Visual Studio Code and vscode-go extension both have their own issues lists on github.

The problem has been fixed. Check [this](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/999).